# Error de conexión entre spring boot y postgres con docker

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker

Estoy intentando hacer conexión entre una aplicación spring boot con java 17 y postgres 15.4, pero me está dando el error: **org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to micros-postgres15.4:5434 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.**

cabe resaltar que el mismo error me da tanto para postgres ejecutándose localmente sin docker y también localmente contenerizado en un docker, en ambos casos ya edité el archivo postgresql.conf para permitir conexiones remotas: listen_addresses = '*'

mi configuración de spring boot actualmente está así:

```
server.port: 8889
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://micros-postgres15.4:5434/my_management
    username: jsm
    password: root
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    show-sql: false
```

mi Dockerfile está así:

```
FROM openjdk:17
EXPOSE 8889
ADD my-management-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar my8.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar","meal8.jar"]
```

y ejecuto los comandos docker para spring boot así:

```
docker build -t my8:v1 .
docker network create docker-test-v1
docker run -p 8889:8889 --name my-container --network docker-test-v1 my8:v1
```

y así los comandos docker para postgres:

```
docker run -p 5434:5434 --name micros-postgres15.4 --network docker-test-v1 -e POSTGRES_USER=jsm -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root -e POSTGRES_DB=my_management -e POSTGRES_PORT=5434 -d postgres:15.4-alpine
```

gracias desde ya por la ayuda.

Comment: asi? creo que el problema es el nombre con punto   `docker run -p 5434:5434 --name "micros-postgres15.4" --network docker-test-v1 -e POSTGRES_USER=jsm -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root -e POSTGRES_DB=my_management -e POSTGRES_PORT=5434 -d postgres:15.4-alpine`

Answer (score 0):

En [la documentación de PostgreSQL para Docker](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/postgres#environment-variables), no encuentro nada sobre el uso de la variable POSTGRES_PORT para definir el puerto de conexión, es posible que se esté usando el puerto por defecto (5432).

Siempre puedes dejar el puerto por defecto en PostgreSQL y mapearlo al que necesites en Docker, con `-p 5434:5432`